# Rails Join Query in Model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm building a marketplace app. I want to define conditions for a listing to expire and be taken off the site.

In my listing model, I have the below. This works as is.

```
def self.not_expired 
  where('(updated_at >= ? or user_id = ?) and inventory > ?', Date.current - 30.day, 24, 0)
end
```

Then in my index method in the controller, I have `@listings = Listing.not_expired` and in my view I have a do loop that goes through and displays these listings.

In my model, I want to add an OR condition which is a field from the User model. Sellers can check a box to ask that we hide their listings from the site. In the user model, I have a Boolean field called `hidelistings`. Listing and User model are joined with user_id.

How do I add a join to the method above to say the below

```
def not_expired
   where(same as above) OR listing.user.hidelistings == "f"
end
```

The above syntax doesn't work. I'm using SQLite.

Comment: Try to do this: `Listing.joins("INNER JOIN users ON users.id = listings.user_id AND users. hidelistings = false").not_expired`. This way you take into account only the users that want their listings to be shown.

Comment: I use `Listing.notexpired` on a lot of different controller methods (index, category, vendor, etc.) so I'd prefer to keep the conditions in the model method so I have it all together. How do I do the join within the method?

Comment: Define a scope (or a class method if your prefer) like this: `scope :listable,  ->joins("INNER JOIN users ON users.id = listings.user_id AND users. hidelistings = false")`  and then modify the body of not_expired method to use this scope like this:  `listable.where('(updated_at >= ? or user_id = ?) and inventory > ?', Date.current - 30.day, 24, 0)`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later today and report back. If you want to put this into an answer, please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :listings
end

class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end

@listings = Listing.not_expired
```

## First solution

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  scope :listable, ->{ 
    joins("INNER JOIN users
           ON users.id = listings.user_id
           AND users. hidelistings = 'f'") 
  }

  def self.not_expired
    listable.where('(updated_at >= ? OR user_id = ?) AND inventory > ?', Date.current - 30.day, 24, 0)
  end
end
```

This will generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" INNER JOIN users ON users.id = listings.user_id AND users. hidelistings = 'f' WHERE ((listings.updated_at >= '2015-02-03' ... ))
```

## Second solution

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  def self.not_expired
    joins(:user).where("((listings.updated_at >= ? OR user_id = ?) AND inventory > ?) OR users.hidelistings = 'f')", Date.current - 30.day, 2)
  end
end
```

This will generate the following SQL:

```
SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "listings"."user_id" WHERE (((listings.updated_at >= '2015-02-03' OR user_id = 2) OR users.hidelistings = 'f'))
```

If you want you can refactor the condition with AREL to improve readability.

Comment: Thanks, I used the first solution since it was cleaner and didn't mess with what I had already.